# PHP MVC share function across all views

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm just getting into using Mini3 MVC framework but am struggling with the concept of where to code a function that is to be used by ALL views. Mini3 is here: https://github.com/panique/mini3

I have a function called `auto_version` that creates a name for CSS files based on the modified date/time, so I can call it by `<?php echo auto_version('css/style.css');?>`

I need to call this on every view, so to me, the place to call the function is in `application/view/_templates/header.php`.

Where is the best place to code the function though? Does it go in the Helper class in `application/libs/helper.php` or elsewhere?

Is it good practice to call a function from a view like this or am I breaking MVC rules?

If I have to call my function in every view controller (e.g. in `application/Controller/HomeController.php` and `SongsController.php`), it's a lot of code replication which doesn't sit right with me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fantastic example using mini2 MVC from the same author - https://github.com/panique/huge

This has really helped me understand how things should be done